# Segmentation fault(core dumped) in c language

Tags: c

I am trying to create a very basic program in C using structures and using the string.h library, but its giving me the segmentation fault error, I cant seem to find the problem with the syntax. Here's the code I am trying to run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct people
{
    char name[50];
    int age;
    int number;
};

int main()
{
    
    struct people people1, people2;
    printf("What is your name:");
    strcpy("Welcome %s !",&people1.name);
    printf("what is your age?");
    scanf("%d", &people1.age);
    printf("Write your phone number:");
    scanf("%d", &people1.number);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: After `what is your name` you are missing a `scanf` line.

Comment: `strcpy("Welcome %s !",&people1.name);` doesn't make sense; you probably meant to use `printf`.

Comment: The `strcpy` causes the coredump, because it should be a `printf`. You are writing to a string literal, which causes UB.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have *missed* an scanf command to get the name of people1.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer with some actual code

Answer (score 0):

> strcpy("Welcome %s !",&people1.name);

Apart from the logic in the context (you probably wanted printf() instead), notice that strcpy() accepts 2 parameters, and copies the *SECOND one* into the *FIRST one*.

So in this case, you are copying from a variable into a *string constant*! It could even work in *some rare situation*, but don't do it: likely, the effect of the statement makes the computer unhappy because you are trying to write read-only memory (i.e. the content of the program itself), and so a segmentation fault comes out.

Moreover, you should not use the ampersand & with *people1.name*, because that designates already an address, which is what strcpy() wants.

Lastly, the ampersand & is correct instead in the line

> scanf("%d", &people1.age);

because *people1.age* does not represent an address but an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

After what is your name you are missing a scanf line.
Also your usage of `strcpy` is wrong, but I assume that this was just a typo.

```
int main()
{
    struct people people1, people2;
    printf("What is your name:");
    scanf(" %s", people1.name);
    printf("Welcome %s !\n", people1.name);
    printf("what is your age?");
    scanf("%d", &people1.age);
    printf("Write your phone number:");
    scanf("%d", &people1.number);
    return 0;
}
```